# Any idea why asi-http-request has started failing on this code that it used to work on?

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

Short snippet here (synchronous just for sample, normally we use async and both happen to fail the same way now...  Note that url2 is already setup and works fine against our server if I use it manually.  Also, please forgive any simple typos as my Mac is being stupid today and refusing to copy/paste, forcing me to retype...  Luckily I'm more in need of general "way of doing things" help rather than "fix my syntax" in this case as it used to work, but (without any changes) failed sometime in the last month (possibly with the iOS 6 update).  :-)

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request2=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url2];
request2.requestMethod=@"GET";
[request2 addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[request2 setDelegate:self];
[request2 startSynchronous];
NSError *error=[request2 error];
```

The returned error code is "1", but I can't find an error code list in the asi-http-request docs to find out what it might mean.  Also, note that I've updated to the very latest asi-http-request version available (still pretty old though).

Comment: +1 for properly *not using* the Xcode tag.

Comment: @H2CO3 don't forget the +1 for properly _not using_ the PHP tag ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error code is `ASIConnectionFailureErrorType` (it's an enumeration at the top of ASIHTTPrequest.h).

Line 188 of ASIHTTPRequest.h says

```
// If error code is = ASIConnectionFailureErrorType (1, Connection failure occurred) - inspect [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSUnderlyingErrorKey] for more information
```

and the only place it's referenced in code is in ASIHTTPRequest.m, in the `handleStreamError` method (line 3644).

So that's where I'd start :)

Comment: Looks like it's kicking out the server's SSL certificate for some reason.  Guess I'll move back to the server and work on that side.  Odd, it appears that the certificate on there expired about 2 years ago, yet it had been working fine until recently!  :-)

Comment: Could it be an iOS 6 related issue. I have had some code that also suddenly stopped working at the end of September that is also using ASIHTTPRequest. I am troubleshooting right now, but it looks to me that that library may be broken with iOS6

Comment: It's not the library - I'm using it in iOS6 with no problems at all. However, there might be some change in iOS6 with certificates etc that might prevent the library working _in some cases_.